# Custom EditText which prevents user input after n characters

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to get edit text to behave in this way:

User can input maximum of 10 characters, when focus is lost from edit text the current text gets formatted like: 0123456789 -> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9.

So the edit text itself can have up to 19 characters. After the focus is gained again user cannot input before he/she removes characters.

Currently I have been hacking the text with TextWatcher and the solution doesn't look pretty (needed flags,handler and runnable). So any ideas if there are some nice ways to do this, maybe overriding some super class methods or something like that?

Br,
Niko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can still implement `TextWatcher` to let user enter just 10 characters. Whenever user enters 10 characters, set that `EditText` to non-editable. And also set OnFocusChangeListener to it. So whenever it looses focus, change its text and add space after each character except for the last one.

Comment: I didn't get the TextWatcher approach code look that good, so looking for other aspects like JeremyS pointed out.

Comment: Cannot change edit text to non-editable because user still should be allowed to remove characters, only prevented to input after n chars.

Comment: So your TextWatcher will take care of that. Don't allow user to enter 11th character in your TextWatcher.

Comment: But when the formatting of the text gets done, TextWatcher will prevent it, because it doesn't allow more than 10 characters to be inserted to the edit text.

Comment: Is there any way to use OnKeyboardActionListener without implementing custom keyboard?

Comment: Why do you need that. you already have `edittext.setOnKeyListener()` in android.

Comment: KeyListener only gets done and back presses, not for letters or numbers. Only works properly with hardware keyboard.

Comment: Ok. But you should then post this question as a new question. Not in this thread. It may help you.

Comment: Yeah i guess so, the problem expanded and the original problem is not the actual problem, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating your own class extending EditText and override the onTextChanged method. Here, after x amount of characters typed, set it to read-only/unfocused/whatever, and format it yourself. or maybe onKeyDown?

Comment: overriding onKeyDown could be the best option here. When user tries to enter number and length < 10 it's allowed and super call made, also with remove key and enter is allowed, but everything else ignored. So no need for making edit text read only or add textwatcher, will report the results tomorrow when I test it.

Comment: OnKeyDown would have been the best way, but it doesn't recognize anything else than back button so cannot use it.

Comment: Also setting to read only after n characters is unusable because user still should be able to remove characters, unfocused also not an option here.

Comment: Then how about that onTextChanged then?